# Update SO Line Extension Fields on Inventory ID Entry (Commit)

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am building a DAC extension on POVendorInventory and SOLine to display my new PO vendor inventory fields on the document details of an SO.  I am to display the fields with the following code, but unable to have the fields update when the Inventory ID field is entered.

**ExtensionSOLine.cs**

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.SO;


namespace PX.KWW.PreferredVendorFields.DAC
{
    public class ExtensionSOLine : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
    {
        #region UsrPreferredVendorID
        public abstract class usrPreferredVendorID : BqlInt.Field<usrPreferredVendorID> { }

        [PXInt()]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOLine.inventoryID, InventoryItem.preferredVendorID>))]
        public virtual int? UsrPreferredVendorID { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrPreferredVendorLocationID
        public abstract class usrPreferredVendorLocationID : BqlInt.Field<usrPreferredVendorLocationID> { }

        [PXInt()]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOLine.inventoryID, InventoryItem.preferredVendorLocationID>))]
        public virtual int? UsrPreferredVendorLocationID { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorTotalQty
        public abstract class usrVendorTotalQty : BqlInt.Field<usrVendorTotalQty> { }

        [PXInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Vendor Qty", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<ExtensionPOVendorInventory.usrVendorTotalQty,
                           InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
                               On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>>,
                           Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<ExtensionSOLine.usrPreferredVendorID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID, Equal<ExtensionSOLine.usrPreferredVendorLocationID>>>>>))]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorTotalQty { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrNearestWhsQty
        public abstract class usrVendorNearestWhsQty : BqlInt.Field<usrVendorNearestWhsQty> { }

        [PXInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nearest Wh Qty", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<ExtensionPOVendorInventory.usrVendorNearestWhseQty,
                           InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
                               On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>>,
                           Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorLocationID>>>>>))]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorNearestWhsQty { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorTransitTime
        public abstract class usrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse : BqlInt.Field<usrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse> { }

        [PXInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Transit Time", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<ExtensionPOVendorInventory.usrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse,
                           InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
                               On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>>,
                           Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorLocationID>>>>>))]
        public virtual int? UsrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorContractPrice
        public abstract class usrVendorContractPrice : BqlDecimal.Field<usrVendorContractPrice> { }

        [PXDecimal(2)]
        //[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Contract Price", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<ExtensionPOVendorInventory.usrVendorContractPrice,
                           InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
                               On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>>,
                           Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorID>,
                               And<POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID, Equal<InventoryItem.preferredVendorLocationID>>>>>))]
        public virtual decimal? UsrVendorContractPrice { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**ExtensionPOVendorInventory**

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.PO;

namespace PX.KWW.PreferredVendorFields.DAC
{
    public class ExtensionPOVendorInventory : PXCacheExtension<POVendorInventory>
    {
        #region UsrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse
        public abstract class usrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse : BqlInt.Field<usrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse> { }
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nearest WH Lead Time", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual int? UsrLeadTimeFromNearestWhse { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrNearestWhse
        public abstract class usrNearestWhse : BqlString.Field<usrNearestWhse> { }
        [PXDBString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nearest WH", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual string UsrNearestWhse { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorContractPrice
        public abstract class usrVendorContractPrice : BqlDecimal.Field<usrVendorContractPrice> { }
        [PXDBDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contract Price", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual decimal? UsrVendorContractPrice { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorNearestWhseQty
        public abstract class usrVendorNearestWhseQty : BqlInt.Field<usrVendorNearestWhseQty> { }
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nearest WH Qty", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorNearestWhseQty { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrVendorTotalQty
        public abstract class usrVendorTotalQty : BqlInt.Field<usrVendorTotalQty> { }
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Qty", IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorTotalQty { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a known limitation of PXDBScalar, that attribute won't refresh the query. I had to use FieldUpdated event on dependent field and manually compute the value to update it. PXFormula does refresh better but has other limitation as well.

Comment: As a workaround you can try writing your own Attributes with FieldSelecting event handler and load the value for each field correspondingly to the value of the Inventory Item field.

Comment: Thank you for the input but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to implement this.  I have not been able to find much online and as this is my first Acu code project, It's hard to wrap my brain around.